# Moving counters along a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, grid, 2d

I have three classes and am trying to make a game whereby users move along a grid depending on what is rolled by a die.

I have my main BoardGame class, containing the GUI and the counters which currently are Jlabel images (i'm open to suggestions as to what I could use instead of a JLabel - i wasnt so sure myself). I have a Grid class which I have arranged into a 2D array and called an instance of in the BoardGame class, and I have a die class which rolls a random number from 1-6.

I am trying to get me counters to start at the first square on the grid, and then advance in a left-to-right-right-to-left fashion. I am unsure however of how to make the counters move through the grid in the first place. Hopefully, if I can figure this out, I believe I can then implement them moving a specific amount via the die.

Thanks for the help in advance

GameBoard class:

```
public class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private JLabel Board;
private JLabel GreenDot;
private JLabel redDot;
private JButton startButton;
private Grid grid;
private Die die;

/**
 * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Grid grid = new Grid();
            GameBoard inst = new GameBoard(grid);
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public GameBoard(Grid grid) {
    super();
    this.grid = grid;
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        {
            redDot = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(redDot);
            redDot.setText("jLabel1");
            redDot.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/download.png")));
            redDot.setBounds(220, 434, 20, 12);
            redDot.setBorder(new LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0), 1, false));

        }
        {
            GreenDot = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(GreenDot);
            GreenDot.setText("jLabel1");
            GreenDot.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/3d-green-ball-th.png")));
            GreenDot.setBounds(222, 453, 21, 13);
            GreenDot.setBorder(new LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0), 1, false));

        }
        {
            startButton = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(startButton);
            startButton.setText("Start Game");
            startButton.setBounds(64, 443, 83, 23);
        }
        {
            Board = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Board);
            Board.setLayout(null);
            Board.setText("jLabel1");
            Board.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/board.jpg")));
            Board.setBounds(204, -1, 742, 484);
        }


        pack();
        this.setSize(963, 523);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //add your error handling code here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Grid class:

```
public class Grid {

int[][] multi = {
        { 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        { 0,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
};
```

}

Die class:

```
public class Die {

public Die() {
}

public void dieRoll() {
      int SIDES = 6; 

        int roll = (int) (Math.random() * SIDES) + 1;

        System.out.println(roll);
}
```

}

Comment: You're going to have to think about it differently.  Instead of trying to move an object "physically", you can fake it.  You could setup a series of `JLabel`s in a grid (maintaining them in a `List` of array) and simply change their `icon` property to indicate where they are on the board - as an idea.  In addition, if your used something like a [`OverlayLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html), you might even be able to overlay multiple layers of grids so you can add other elements

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this would be to change the die class so it has

```
{
    private int sides;
    public Die(int numSides){
        sides = numSides;
    }
    public int roll(){
        return (int) (Math.random() * SIDES) + 1
    }
}
```

Then you can roll a six sided die like so

```
//this creates the die
Die sixSides = new Die(6);
//this rolls the die and prints the roll
System.out.print("That roll got you a " + sixSides.roll());
```

to move along a 2D array, all you need to do is use the modulus and you need to create a point object class

```
public position move(int num, int x, int y){//input is dice roll int then current position

    for(int i = 0; i < num;i++){
        if(i%10==0){
           y++;
           x = 0;
        }else{
           x++;
        } 
    }  
    return new point(x,y);
}
```

To access the x and y positions of the point object you would need to write get and set methods for the object.
something like this

```
point player1 = new point(0,0);
int xposition = player1.getX
```